# Rails created_at query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In rails i made the function (here i have a time of the format 2011-09-01T14:24:09.090Z going inside)

```
time = params[:time].sub!(/\..*/,'')
@pictures = Picture.all
finalPictures = []
@pictures.each do |picture|
date = picture.created_at
if date > time
  finalPictures.push(picture)
 end
end
@pictures = finalPictures
```

This was to find all pictures made after a certain time. It yielded 4 results (all made after) I replaced this with the query.

```
@pictures = Picture.where("created_at >= :time", {:time => time})
```

this should obviously find all pictures made after the time. But it yields nothing. if i replace it with

```
@pictures = Picture.where("created_at <= :time", {:time => time})
```

It yields the proper results, what is going on here. I know it seems like i should just use the correct method, but that means i need to change a LOT of queries (which i guess i didn't test enough). Could i be getting this behaviour because of my time format, should i change it in another way (and how if i do need to)? or is this how the created_at function works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be concerned with your time formatting, as the object you pass in to the query should be of DateTime, Time, or Date. If you don't have one of these, you'll need to adjust it to be one:

```
time = DateTime.parse(params[:time])
```

As to why your times are not being scoped correctly, you should have a look at the query that's generated and logged in `log/development.log` to see if it is working correctly when executed on its own.

Calling `Picture.all` and then iterating is a really bad way to do this, as I'm sure you've realized, so it's important to get the query working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'm doing in this kind of situations, I go to rails console and check raw SQL.

To do so, set in rails console:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

then run your method

```
Picture.where("created_at >= :time", {:time => time})
```

Then you will see what's going on, cause this should works.

Comment: If you like seeing the SQL logged directly, you might want to put that sort of thing in your `.irbrc` so it can load all the time. Wrap it in an conditional to trigger only if ActiveRecord is defined.

Comment: Thanks @tadman, I'm doing this, but for this answer I just wanted to make this simpler:)